# How can you play Steam games with nvidia-optimus laptop?

Tags: laptop, games, nvidia-optimus, steam

What is the best way to start a Steam game on a NVIDIA Optimus laptop with Ubuntu 12.04 installed and the latest version of bumblebee installed?

If I call Steam with `optirun steam` and then choose the game I want to play, I get the following error:

```
The program 'hl2_linux' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter)'.
  (Details: serial 125 error_code 9 request_code 14 minor_code 0)
  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
   that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
   To debug your program, run it with the --sync command line
   option to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
Missing shutdown function for DevShotGenerator_Init() : DevShotGenerator_Shutdown()
Missing shutdown function for MapReslistGenerator_Init() : MapReslistGenerator_Shutdown()
Missing shutdown function for COM_InitFilesystem( m_StartupInfo.m_pInitialMod ) : COM_ShutdownFileSystem()
Missing shutdown function for Steam3Client().Activate() : Steam3Client().Shutdown()
/home/user/.local/share/Steam/SteamApps/user/Team Fortress 2/hl2.sh: line 72: 20567 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) ${GAME_DEBUGGER} "${GAMEROOT}"/${GAMEEXE} "$@"
Game removed: AppID 440 "Team Fortress 2", ProcID 20567 
saving roaming config store to 'sharedconfig.vdf'
roaming config store 2 saved successfully
^C[68042.116376] [WARN]Received Interrupt signal.
```

If I run `steam` without the `optirun` option, I can go a little further into running the game, hearing the starting music on a black screen, but still fails later on in the process.

Should I call the game I want to play with a special `optirun` command instead of `optirun steam`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Valve recommends using primusrun for running Steam games on the NVIDIA GPU.

See the following guide for help on doing so:

https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=6316-GJKC-7437

Comment: Thanks, `primusrun steam` worked wonderfully.

Answer (score 11):

Check these links - You need to change game properties as shown below

- Right click on TF2 in your library
- Click Properties
- Click Set Launch Options
- If you only have optirun, enter: `optirun %command%`

The above did not work for me and I had to set the launch options as

```
LD_PRELOAD="libpthread.so.0 libGL.so.1" __GL_THREADED_OPTIMIZATIONS=1 optirun %command%
```

Check these discussions:

- http://steamcommunity.com/groups/LinuxOptimus/discussions/0/846944052733804503/
- http://steamcommunity.com/groups/LinuxOptimus/discussions/1/864951657810665792/

If this does not work download the `hl2-optirun.sh` to below location and run it.

```
/home/user/Steam/SteamApps/'account_name'/Team Fortress 2/
```

Comment: The `LD_PRELOAD…` options works for me, as does `hl2-optirun.sh`. Neither of the official options work. (I'm using a Dell XPS 17 L702X.)

Comment: Your second command worked for me too (with Dota 2). Thank you!