# How can I play Team Fortress 2 (TF2) with bumblebee in Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-optimus, steam, bumblebee, hybrid-graphics

Previously in (K)ubuntu 13.04, I could play Team Fortress 2 (TF2) on my nvidia-optimus laptop using bumblebee.

I would [do this](https://askubuntu.com/a/259117/53508) by setting its launch options in Steam to

```
LD_PRELOAD="libpthread.so.0 libGL.so.1" __GL_THREADED_OPTIMIZATIONS=1 optirun %command%
```

Since the upgrade to (K)ubuntu 13.10, TF2 will not start from steam. Using the `hl2-optirun.sh` script from the above answer also fails on the terminal with

```
./hl2_linux: error while loading shared libraries: libturbojpeg.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How can I get TF2 to run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Ubuntu 13.10 is missing a file that bumblebee expects to find. To recreate it,

```
$ cd /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/
$ sudo ln -s libturbojpeg.so.0.0.0 libturbojpeg.so
```

This is actually documented [elsewhere](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/fix-bumblebee-libturbojpegso-issue-in.html) on the internet, but you have to do this even if you are on a 64-bit system, as TF2 only runs as 32-bit.

Comment: As an addendum, I now set TF2's launch options to `primusrun %command%`. (FWIW I've moved to Arch, but this should work in Ubuntu, too.)